# How to get sum of this array?

Tags: c

I'm troubleshooting my code right now and I'm trying to get the sum of the first and second score. However, it results to a million value.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    int main ()
    {
     int points [10], n, i, sum = 0, ave;
     float max, average;
     printf("Enter number of activities to compute: ");
     scanf("%d", &n );
     printf("Enter total points possible: ");
     scanf("%f", &max);
     for(i=0; i < n; ++i){
     printf("Enter points earned for each activity %d: ", i+1);
     scanf("%d", &points [i]);
     sum += points [i];
     printf("%d", &sum);
     }
     }
```

When running the code this is the result:

```
Enter number of activities to compute: 2
Enter total points possible: 20
Enter points earned for each activity 1: 10
6618600Enter points earned for each activity 2: 5
6618600
```

My goal is to make it 15.
Thanks!

Comment: `printf("%d", &sum);` -> `printf("%d", sum);` Also, you may want to move that to be outside/after the loop so that it is only printed after the final sum has been calculated. And you may want to add a newline (`\n`) to make it easier to understand the output.

Comment: If your compiler did not warn you about a type mismatch in argument for format specifier `%d` you should turn up warning level.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to put `&` in `printf`. Adding `&` will print the address of the variable.

```
 printf("%d", sum);
```

Comment: Actually it will cause undefined behaviour if you provide anything different than a `int` value (after type promotion).

Comment: Adding the `&` will *pass* an address to `printf` but it will still treat it as an `int` and might very well only use part of the passed value and use wrong representation.

Comment: @Gerhardh Thanks. That makes sense. What should be the ideal way to then print the address ? As hex using %x?

Comment: No, `%x` expects an `unsigned int`. That is equally wrong. There is only one valid way to print an address: `%p` and you must cast the address to `void*` if it is a pointer to any other type. But that is not really what the question was about. I just wanted to point out that "doesn't need" should actually be "must not"